# Gatsby prefetching common.js from other sites

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I have a network of Gatsby sites in which the sites are different language versions of the same site, so I have "alternate"-tags like these for SEO-purposes:

```
<link data-react-helmet="true" rel="alternate" href="https://mylocalsite.co.uk" hreflang="en-GB">
```

When running a Lighthouse PageSpeed Insights test though, it tells me to "Avoid enormous network payload" and shows me a list of the common.js-file from every other site in the network, like they are being prefetched in the background.

How can I disable this behaviour?

Apart from the `<link>`-tags, a language-switcher using regular `<a href="https://anotherlocalsite.com">` links between the sites is the only way the sites are "connected". No Gatsby `Links` are used.

[image]

Comment: It would help us give a helpful answer if you could paste the code of your SEO component AND the resulting meta html code when you run `gatsby build`.

Comment: What do you mean "regular links"? Gatsby links have a built in prefetching behavior while a tags do not. Which one do you use to connect your sites? Edit your question with your React JSX link code.

Comment: Edited my question to make it clear that no Gatsby-Links are being used. The resulting meta html code is as posted in the question, regular link tags (not Link-tags).